# Why does scala spawn multiple threads even when not using Akka or parallel collections?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, concurrency

I've written a simple program that sums numbers it reads off of a file I specify. When I watch it run in htop, there are ~6 threads associated with the program. It is also running on all of my cores.

The problem is I have no idea why it is spawning multiple threads. I am not using parallel collections, Akka, or explicitly calling anything related to multithreading. I am using some mutable data structures, so I have concerns with data race condition and want to understand how scala (or could be underlying java/jvm) generates threads.

Comment: Could be JVM internal threads. Take a thread dump (`kill -3 java_pid` on Linux, or use JDK `jstack` util) and see for yourself.

Comment: @VictorSorokin thanks. I used `jcmd Thread.print` to get a thread dump. I learned that it was mostly JVM threads related to monitoring, garbage collection, etc and only one Main thread. Thanks.